# Why isn't this keyframe animation working?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm trying to scale the box up and back down again.

This is my first time using keyframe animations and I'm not really sure the proper way to invoke them.

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fzvkf)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="bounce"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 
    0%   { -webkit-transform: scale(1);   } 
    50%  { -webkit-transform: scale(2); } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(2);   } 
} 
@keyframes pulse { 
    0%   { transform: scale(1);   } 
    50%  { transform: scale(2); } 
    100% { transform: scale(2);   } 
}
.wrap {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:#999999;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.bounce {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#333333;
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:300px;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
}
.bounce.go {
    top:50px;
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse 1s 1; 
    animation-name: pulse 1s 1; 
}
```

JS:

```
$('.bounce').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('.bounce').hasClass('go')) {
        $('.bounce.go').removeClass('go');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('go');
    }
});
```

Comment: Off-topic: your jQuery code is outdated and verbose. `$('.bounce').on('click', function() { $(this).toggleClass('go'); });`

Comment: @NOPENOPENOPE if my answer was correct then please click on the tick.. Thank  you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `-webkit-animation-name to -webkit-animation`